# How to Enter PayPal information into NetSuite with Web Services?

Tags: web-services, paypal, netsuite

I am having an issue getting PayPal Payment information into NetSuite via Web Services.  After setting up PayPal within NetSuite and setting up all of the Test Accounts with PayPal we have all of the external endpoints functioning properly with PayPal on our web site.  When we go to try and import the Sales Order with the new PayPal Payment information most of the data doesn't transfer.

Specifically the "payPalStatus" and "paypalAuthId" fields available to us through web services are both left blank in NetSuite.  The "payPalTranId" field is the only one that remains populated upon submitting the order Via Web Services.  When trying to Capture against this Authorization inside of NetSuite we cannot.

If anyone can point us in the right direction on how to resolve this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You for your time!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK those fields are for when you are using a Netsuite hosted web site and their PayPal integration. You can try filing a case.

If you have the payPalTranId you can write an integration against the PayPal API to capture your sales. The PP API is pretty straight-forward.